# System.getenv() not showing last added environment variables

Tags: kotlin, ubuntu, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I want to access to some environment variables that I set on `.bashrc` but i cannot get it using `System.getenv()`, I am using Intellij-idea ultimate on Ubuntu Linux.

On .bashrc i have:

```
export TWILIO_SMS_SERVICE_SID="XXXXXXXXXX"
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID="XXXXXXXXXX"
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Running on command line `$ echo $TWILIO_SMS_SERVICE_SID` i got the correct value `XXXXXXXXXX`.

But this `System.getenv("TWILIO_SMS_SERVICE_SID")` returns null.

When i run this, i got all the environment variables but not the last that i added:

```
println("Environment variables: ")
System.getenv().forEach { (key, value) -> println("$key: $value") }
```

Do you know what the causes might be or how to fix it?

p.s: sorry, I have no idea how to do a POC about this, I am open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you start the Java program directly from IntelliJ IDEA? Depending on how you started it, it might not have the environment variables set, as `~/.bashrc` might only be evaluated when you start a bash shell. It should work if you start IntelliJ IDEA (or just your Java program) from the bash shell that has the environment variables set.

Comment: Yes, now i tried starting IntelliJ IDEA using the command line ./bin/idea.sh and it worked!